# Keeping a git fork in sync while adding custom github actions

Tags: git, github, continuous-integration, github-actions, git-clone

In short: I want to fork a repository, keep it in sync with the original, but also add some GitHub actions to the fork.

---

I want to fork a git repository, on a public gitlab instance, to a clone that is hosted on our github enterprise instance.

- The fork should be kept in sync with the original: at least the main and dev branch should always be up-to-date with the original repository. I found some github actions to enable this, such as `wei/git-sync`
- Contributions to the upstream repository will be developed and tested by my team on the fork, before contributing back to the upstream.

Now I also want to add a CI/CD pipeline, via github actions, to the forked repository.

- As far as I am aware, github actions need to be part of each branch that they are run on.
- All CI actions should run on the dev and main branches, as well as on any feature branches that we create from those.
- when we contribute back, the github actions should not be part of that contribution. They would not work on the gitlab instance anyway.

How can I reconcile these needs?

- How can I run these github actions on the branches of the cloned repository, while also keeping those branches in sync with the upstream repository?
- How can I keep our contributions clean, containing only our changes to the original code, without our custom github actions?

Is there a way to execute the github actions on each branch and each commit, but not be part of the branch itself?
Or is there some clever combination of merge/rebase tricks that would automatically include the github actions but not result in a total mess of a commit history?

What is the best practice for this sort of problem? How is this normally solved?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is: the `main` and `dev` branch from GitLab should be mirrored *exactly* in your GitHub fork. No file of any kind should be added there. In particular, no `.github/workflow/xxx.yml` actions should be in `main`.
The GitHub branches mirroring GitLab's `main` and `dev` should be protected, and nothing should be directly push to them.

That means... said GitHub branches (mirroring GitLab's) should *not* be called `main` or `dev`, but, for instance, `gitlab-main-mirror` and `gitlab-dev-mirror`.

That way, you can use `main` for your GitHub actions.

You would therefore have:

- `gitlab-main-mirror`: This branch is an exact mirror of the `main` branch of the GitLab repository.
- `gitlab-dev-mirror`: This branch is an exact mirror of the `dev` branch of the GitLab repository.
- `main`: This branch is based on `gitlab-main-mirror`, but it also contains your GitHub Actions files.
- `dev`: This branch is based on `gitlab-dev-mirror`, but it also contains your GitHub Actions files.

With that setup, `main` and `dev` are the branches where your team does its work. The `sync-with-upstream.yml` workflow is configured to keep `gitlab-main-mirror` and `gitlab-dev-mirror` in sync with the GitLab repository.

When you want to update `main` or `dev` with the latest changes from GitLab, you would do a merge from the corresponding `gitlab-*` branch. This could be automated with another GitHub Actions workflow if desired.

This approach allows you to have exact mirror branches (`gitlab-main-mirror` and `gitlab-dev-mirror`) while still having working branches (`main` and `dev`) that include your GitHub Actions files. Your team would need to remember to pull changes from the `gitlab-*` branches before starting new work or making a contribution back to the GitLab repository.

When contributing back to GitLab, you would start from `gitlab-main-mirror` or `gitlab-dev-mirror`, cherry-pick or apply the changes you want to contribute, and then push or create a merge request from there. This ensures that no GitHub Actions files are included in the contribution.

The synchronization can take place on a regular schedule:

```yaml
name: Sync with Upstream

on:
  schedule:
    - cron: '0 0 * * *'  # Run daily at 00:00

jobs:
  sync-main:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - name: Checkout git repo
      uses: actions/checkout@v3
      with:
        ref: 'gitlab-main-mirror' # specify the branch to checkout

    - name: Pull upstream changes to main mirror
      uses: wei/git-sync@v3
      with:
        destination_repo: ${{ github.repository }}
        source_repo: '<original-gitlab-repo-url>'
        source_branch: 'main'
        destination_branch: 'gitlab-main-mirror'
        github_token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}

  sync-dev:

    needs: sync-main  # Ensures the main sync is done before dev starts

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - name: Checkout git repo
      uses: actions/checkout@v3
      with:
        ref: 'gitlab-dev-mirror' # specify the branch to checkout

    - name: Pull upstream changes to dev mirror
      uses: wei/git-sync@v3
      with:
        destination_repo: ${{ github.repository }}
        source_repo: '<original-gitlab-repo-url>'
        source_branch: 'dev'
        destination_branch: 'gitlab-dev-mirror'
        github_token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
```